# Loop Cut Not Working On Face

Tags: modeling, faces

Soo I was modeling when I came across a face that a loop cut didn't work on. I googled it and everyone was saying it would be like an interior face behind the normal face but it was the only face.

Here are some pics

[image]
https://snag.gy/OQ5zjF.jpg

[image]

https://snag.gy/6m0E4N.jpg

Comment: that face is an ngon (has more than 4 vertices ) and the loop cut won't work on it, use the knife tool to complete the cut on that face.

Comment: The polygon in question has 6 vertices. Loop cut will not work with ngons (polygons of more than 4 vertices)